# Can someone help me with enchantment table Particles

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to get the enchantment table particle to stay floating in the air but all of my testing has failed and it keeps falling and then disappearing. So my question is, is there a way you can make a particle stay suspended in mid air?  An extra question is can you make a particle bend when it is summoned in a line?

Comment: So what are you trying to say?

Answer (score 3):

**I explained this using the enchantmenttable particle, but it also works with the portal particles**

I've been having trouble with this too, and I think I found the solution!

When you do "`/particle enchantmenttable ~ ~ ~ 0 0 0 0 10`", you should get just the particle falling. (To stop it from falling, there's no other way than placing a block underneath, like a barrier or an invisible block like a carpet (to make it invisible you must edit the model file))
What I discovered is that the `[x] [y] [z]` works as normal, and the `[xd] [yd] and [zd]` too, but it gets a little bit complicated with the `[speed]` (note that `[count]` works as normal).

If set to 0, the particles will just fall, but if set to something else, it will determine the radius where the particles will apear, so if set to 4, all the particles will appear in a radius of 4 blocks around `[x] [y] [z]`, in direction of the coordinates set in `[x] [y] [z]`.

**Note that `[y=0]` is the height of your feet, so if you want the particles to go 3 blocks above your head, you'll have to put 5**

But, if `[xd] [yd] [zd]` isn't set to 0, the particles will go somewhere in the sphere with `[x] [y] [z]` as its center and `[xd] [yd] [zd]` as its radius.

**I talk about spheres to simplify, but you can also make ovals or 2D circles**

Now as an example to clarify it, let's say you want 300 particles to appear in a radius of 5 blocks, and they have to go in a circle 2 blocks wide, that is 2 blocks above your head, you type `/particle enchantmenttable ~ ~4 ~ 1 1 1 5 300`!

- `4`is the center of the circle, 2 + 2 (your height + how many blocks above your head)
- `1 1 1` is the radius of the circle, and because you want it to be 2 wide, you simply do 2/2
- `5` is the radius in which the particles appear
- `300` is the number of particles

Sorry for the long post!

I was testing everything I said while doing it, so it might be a little bit overcomplicated as I kept correcting some things that I misunderstood!

Hope it helps!

Comment: "Sorry for the long post!" Don't worry about it. Unlike other sites, we _love_ long, detailed and well written posts :)

Comment: No need to apologize this info was a great help to me thx again.

Comment: One more thing If I'm not able to do this i found another way try this. get a command block type /particle enchantmenttable ~ ~3 ~ 0 0 0 3 100

Comment: one more question its a little harder though is there a way to change the color of an endercrystal.